# Special Characters breaking the Experience Editor

Tags: content-editor, richtext-editor

We recently had an issue while editing a list, a user tried to add é to a list within a rich text editor while working in the Experience Editor, see below. After adding é, the list the user was editing seemed to disappear. A little investigation revealed when adding the special character, all list items had their opacity set to 0. Why is this happening? How do I prevent?

Original:

- resume

[image]

Changed To:

- résumé

[image: Opacity set to 0 after adding special character]

Comment: Where is the opacity set to 0? is it in Content Editor in rich test? or is it in the front end of your website?

Comment: What css class is adding the opacity?

Comment: @MarekMusielak the opacity is set to 0 within the Experience Editor, sorry I misspoke initially but correcting now, when the special character is added. However, when you go into Content Editor, you can change the opacity back to 1, adding images.

Comment: @SashaKachanov no css class, this is coming from styling on the element.